# search string value with wild card in another string java

Tags: java, string-matching

Suppose I have string value

```
String strValue1 = "This is the 3TB value"; 
String strValue2 = "3TB is the value"; 
String strValue3 = "The value is 3TB";
```

No when the user search for `3TB*` then it should match with the strValue2 same like for when user search for `*3TB*` then it should match with strValue1 and for `*3TB` it should match with strValue3

I tried with so many examples but no luck. Is there any wildcard search for string? I can't use any external libraries

Comment: Did you ever hear about regex??

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. But seems that's not working in my case :(

Comment: "But seems that's not working in my case" You should show what you have tried, because regular expressions could be used for this.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Since you stated you cannot use external libraries, I assume this might be homework, so I won't give a direct answer how to use them in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `3TB*` case by using:

```
str.startsWith("3TB")
```

where `str` is the string that you are checking for a match.

You can check the `*3TB*` case by using:

```
str.contains("3TB")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to replace the wildcard `*` by `.+` in the search. The following snippet could be a starting point.

```
String[] strings = {"This is the 3TB value", "3TB is the value", 
                    "The value is 3TB"};
String[] pattern = {"3TB.+", ".+3TB.+", ".+3TB"};
for (String s : strings) {
    for (String p : pattern) {
        if (s.matches(p)) {
            System.out.printf("pattern: %-7s   matches: %s%n", p, s);
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
pattern: .+3TB.+   matches: This is the 3TB value
pattern: 3TB.+     matches: 3TB is the value
pattern: .+3TB     matches: The value is 3TB
```

Comment: Wow! Its working.. I didn't thought about replacing star * with .+  thats why my regex was failing i guess.. Thank you!